# Scala/Lift question rss feed fetch

Tags: java, scala, lift

I'm looking for a simple line or two of code that will grab an rss feed like this php line:
$feed = "URL"
from within a scala object.

I'm using scala/lift with Netbeans or Eclipse if it's relevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest you can do is smth like this, if you do not want  to bother with exceptions or readability:

```
val rssFeed = XML.load( (new URL(feedUrl)).openConnection.getInputStream )
```

Comment: cool, just noting imports:
import scala.xml._
import java.net._

now for my first pattern matching scala function

Comment: got some great info from here from Ted Neward:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala06029.html

Answer (score 2):

The best client API I've used for RSS feed parsing is [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/). It's open source, quite easy to use, and as a Java library, it can be invoked from Scala. I don't know of a pure-Scala library that does this.

Comment: Thanks I came across Rome, but I'm trying to avoid too many additional dependencies at the moment. Rome may be the best long term solution. I'm doing my best to make a lean and mean prototype.